# How to display hex values as plain text in a visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I want to display some hex value in visualforce page. I used this simple line:
[image]

But this is rendered as "This is a paragraph_"

Please advise the correct method to display hex values as plain text without converting them to special charcters.

Comment: Are you using UTF-8 charset encoding on the page?

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the characters. There's a few ways to do so:

```
{!HTMLENCODE(value)}
```

Or...

```
<apex:outputText value="{!value}" escape="true" />
```